# Bounding 2-norm of matrix by spectral radius

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, normed-spaces

I am aware that the spectral radius is bounded above by the 2-norm of the matrix, that is $\rho(A) \le \|A\|_2$ where $\rho$ is the spectral radius.

Does there exist a result such that $\|A\|_2 \le C \rho(A)$ for some known constant $C$?

I'm only concerned about real-valued matrices $A$.

Comment: Suppose A is a nonzero nilpotent matrix....

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Are you taking $A$ in $\mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$ or in a more specific set?

Comment: I'm considering only real-valued matrices. I'll update the question!

Comment: @Tomas To clarify the first comment: the matrix
$A = \pmatrix{0&1\\0&0}$
disproves the existence of such a $C$.